# Is Joseph Weissman doing a reasonable job as diamond mod?

Tags: discussion, support

I have lost all confidence in the judgement of diamond moderator Joseph Weissman. I just don't think he is doing a good job. Cody Gray, the other diamond, dislikes me just as much as Joseph Weissman, but he hasn't act in such capricious abusive ways.

Joseph Weissman just closed another question of mine [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2574/was-nietzsche-a-racist) which was at +2, answered, and dead. Closing a positively voted question with positively voted answers is generally considered an abuse of power, as is closing a question and answers before they can be seen, deleting meta-questions, and banning a user for no reason, all of which Weissman has done.

I don't want to have a person who is not an active member of the community closing questions because he wants to protect nietzsche from honest criticism. We have discussed the racism question, whether it is ok, and I have gotten a reasonable seal of approval on it.

I want the question reopened. I will ask for Joseph Weissman to no longer be a diamond mod on this site. These are two independent issues.

Comment: I'm sorry to have upset you, really. But I'm just wondering if you're not projecting a bit here at this point. Just in passing, here's part of my comment when I closed this question: "[t]his is **simply not about Nietzsche**; it's about the fact that your question is a rant, that it's a blog post masquerading as an honest and innocent question. Closing pending a more neutral formulation of the concern." (emphasis added)

Comment: I am not upset. I don't care what your stated reasons are. This question has been thoroughly vetted by the community, declared fine, answered, upvoted, answer-accepted. You should have left it alone. The only motivation for closing it is to delete it, and the only motivation for deleting it, despite what you say, is to protect nietzsche. Slanted opinionated questions are _allowed_ on all sites here, just as slanted answers are. I have asked that you no longer be diamond mod [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130387/no-confidence-in-diamond-mod-joseph-weissman-at-philosophy).

Comment: The question you linked that has been closed is not really a question, it is a rant.  You don't really want an answer to that question; you've already made up your mind about it.  Hence, you've asked the question in bad faith.

Comment: I almost feel unloved - I suppose I don't intervene enough to merit my own diamond rant?

Comment: Claiming that the question in question has been "thoroughly vetted by the community [and] declared fine" based on the number of upvotes is a bit disingenuous. [I implore you to recall](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/posts/2574/revisions) that many of those upvotes (including, in fact, my own) came *after* I edited the question to take on a decidedly more constructive character. Lots of people probably have not revisited the question to "adjust" their votes after you rolled back my edits. Moreover, a net score of +2 doesn't really count as "thoroughly vetted" or "declared fine".

Comment: Get on it @mixedmath! As for this question, I'm more borderline but ultimately concur with the decision to close it. I did not close it myself because I saw it as an improvement over others (mile-long rants) you have posted, and some members of the community at least seemed to be ok with it. But this whole debate is pointless because you know exactly what you need to do to get it reopened — rewrite it in a more neutral way. If you want to get your views across, this is what you're going to have to do; it's not really a huge sacrifice asking you to be nice to people when you say things, is it?

Comment: @stoicfury: I am not considering it vetted because of the upvotes, but because of the long discussion regarding this. There is absolutely no reason to rewrite it--- if you disagree with what it says, just disagree with it in your answer. It is censorious to prevent "disingenuous" questions, as these are a useful component of this site. I believe, regardless of the results on this, that Joseph Weissman cannot be entrusted with the difficult task of making sure that moderation is not abused to become censorship. As for everyone else, you guys just disagree with me, which is to be expected.

Comment: @mixedmath: A diamond mod should not close questions because he doesn't like the opinion expressed in the text. On physics, we have plenty of people who don't like renormalization, or who don't believe strings are worthwhile, or who hate loops, ranting away, and we answer them, and vote on the merits of the questions and the answers. I know how this politics stuff works, and if you don't leave questions and answers you disagree with alone, and defend the stuff you disagree with as much as the stuff you agree with, you are poisoning the environment and wrecking the value of the site.

Comment: Wow, you really have no clue how the Stack Exchange network works, do you?

Comment: Not sure if trolling or just plain dumb.

Comment: @casperOne: If stackexchange does not work _exactly_ like I imply in the above, there is no point in my participation. This is exactly how it works at physics, math, and biblical hermeneutics (yes, it surprised me too), and this is exactly how internet communities are supposed to function. There is no positive value in a community that does not function this way, and if stackexchange doesn't, I'd rather find out sooner rather than later, so I don't lend support to it.

Comment: @TylerShads: I never troll, I am 100% honest. This is likely something you just have never encountered. You call it "dumb"-- although of course in my worldview, which is generally that of an ordinary physicist, this is the very definition of "not dumb", this kind of anti-political honesty is the opposite of dumb. This does make problems for a person in winning in politics (it is well known that scientists always lose in political debte), but the objective insights you gain are well worth the persecution.

Comment: @RonMaimon Sorry to say, but Stack Exchange operates in a number of ways that are counter to how you believe it *should* behave.  What you do as a result of that is up to you.

Comment: @casperOne: Sorry to say, but you obviously don't know how the good stackexchanges operate. Physics here operates exactly as I believe it should behave, including tolerating rudeness and soapboxing, respecting opinions, etc. This perhaps has misled me regarding the nature of this site.

Comment: Call me naïve, but I suspect that the folks over at the Physics.SE site are not asking leading questions about Feynman being a racist.

Comment: @Joseph is doing a great job as moderator and has since the site started.  (Needless to say: -1.)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It isn't on topic for Physics, it is on topic for moral philosophy. The racism is central to nietzschian philosophy, it isn't incidental--- it is a form of elitism that places the cultured wagner-listening cigar-smoking bosses of 19th century Europe as overlords over the lower classes and races. It is not debatable, the question is a heads-up for others, so that they don't waste their time reading nietzsche, or taking this clown seriously.

Comment: The asking of which is absolutely, unequivocally and unambiguously a mis-application and abuse of the Stack Exchange platform.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Absolutely not! It is a completely reasonable question to say "what's up with all the racism I find in this respected moral philosopher?" It tells you what each school of philosophy thinks about this, which ones deny it, which ones distance themselves from it while accepting other parts, and which ones accept it without comment. Questions are not required to be politically neutral, and they almost never are.

Comment: @Ron: So [remove the biased portions of your question from your question,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objectivity_(science)) and *allow people to answer it,* without giving the impression that you've already made a presumptive answer in your question.  If you want to field your own opinion (assuming you can keep it from being a rant), [**self-answer your own question.**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463)  Again, questions which are already answered by the poster in the question are not questions at all; they are **blog posts.**  You can stand up your own blog for that purpose.

Comment: As an aside, I actually like some of your writing; I find it thought-provoking.  It's too bad you can't seem to find the right place to put it.

Comment: To reiterate: if you are answering your own question, ***put that material in an answer, not in the question.***  As long as you are not personally attacking someone else, posting rants or going off-topic, you can pretty much put whatever you want in an answer.  You would do well to learn a bit more about Stack Exchange; it doesn't work like other online forums. ***Respect the format, and it will respect you.***

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I have been using this site for months, and I know what a functioning moderator community looks like, and a malfunctioning one too. I was first alerted to the problems here by Anixx, who complained on physics that his more philosophical questions couldn't be moved here because the moderation atmosphere was intolerable, and led to valid questions getting deleted. Now I see he was not exaggerating. I respect the format very much--- I did not ask an insincere question--- I gave a racist quote, asked whether it was representative of nietzsche, and how to deal with this academically.

Comment: ... While I don't know how to deal with the racism, other than by completely dropping nietzsche from philosophy curriculum, and using Sade instead, I don't accept as an answer "Oh, you're just misinterpreting..." because I'm not. A better answer "Oh, this is just 19th century crap, the philosophy is not dependent on racism because..." I don't know. My view on this is that nietzsche is a worthless fraud, but so what. My opinion is irrelevant. The line that says "this is the stupidest thing I have read" can't be dropped, because whether black people are numb to pain just isn't debatable.

Comment: You can toss up all the [straw men](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man) you want; my answer will still be the same.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: What straw man?

Comment: Racism. Has. Nothing. To. Do. With. This.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The. question. is. about. racism. Why. does. racism. have. nothing. to. do. with. it? What do you mean? neitzsche's stuff is full of racism. That's just a fact. The question is what to do about it. I wasn't saying anyone here is advocating racism, although by sweeping neitzsche's under the rug, they might be indirectly.

Answer (score 14):

Judging by what I've seen, yes Joseph is doing a reasonable job as a moderator on Philosophy.SE.

Background: Joseph is - as are the other three moderators here - ["Pro Tempore" moderators](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/); that is to say, they are not elected, but [picked and appointed by Stack Exchange staff members](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) such as myself. This is the usual practice prior to a site graduating, as there are not yet enough established community members to [vote in an election](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/).

That said, we do pay close attention to how they behave, and have been known to remove the moderator privileges if they are abused or if the community vehemently disagrees with their actions. They are appointed - later elected - to represent and act on behalf of the community...

And Joseph has done this. I've yet to see a single complaint apart from your own regarding his behavior. Even in regard to your participation here, he was reluctant to step in, attempting to reason with you and soliciting advice from other moderators before taking action. I do not consider his actions unreasonable.

Comment: Um, not at all--- this question should not be closed and there isn't enough traffic on this site to reopen it. This is an abuse of power, plain and simple, and requires some sort of remedy. It is not acceptable behavior to sneakily close an upvoted question. This community is not very good at protecting unpopular opinion as it stands.

Comment: There are three other moderators who can review it, and 23 other users who can vote to re-open if they see fit, 8 of them who've visited the site in the last week. Make the case for your question, and abide by the community's decision.

Comment: There are not 23 active users--- there are exactly 8, of which approximately 4 will vote on such things. It is a difficult thing to bring up criticism of a famous philosopher on issues of racial prejudice or anti-semitism, and there are academic interests who would like the issue buried, since it notoriously follows nietzsche around and stains the reputation of those associated with him, including martin heidegger, hannah arendt, and others in the post-modernist school. This type of thing requires vigorous defence and vigilant attention, so that criticism isn't silenced as it is in academia.

Comment: Again, three other moderators who can re-open with a single vote, and a sufficient number of other users able to vote, edit, and comment in support of your question. First make an honest effort to convince them; if you do not, your allegations here hold little weight.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I will point out that the pattern of deleting material critical of nietzsche for racial bias and anti-semitism is not restricted to this question--- Weissman has deleted and closed 4 such answers already, and banned me from the site for a week. It is difficult to find support for unpopular positions, and I encourage you to run a thorough review of the behavior in question and see for yourself, before coming to judgement.

Comment: @Ron: You're trotting out the *exact same arguments* here again about members of this community trying to protect Nietzsche's image? [As I've said numerous times](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/347/349#349) before [when you've raised the issue](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/342/344#344) of your contributions being closed/deleted, the problem is not the fact that you have opinions. Rather, it's the way in which you present them. I already tried to edit that very question, but you rolled back my edits. You're apparently uninterested in it remaining open.

Comment: @CodyGray: You are not right--- the question has no issues. I don't think _you_ are trying to protect nietzsche, you just don't like opinionated assholes (such as myself). It is Joseph Weissman who is deleting text with the explicitly political goal of protecting nietzsche from criticism, and this is inconsistent with role as diamond mod.

Comment: It's rare for comments from people who are "not right" to receive 3 upvotes and counting. [So long as you adopt a populist justification](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/368/is-joseph-weissman-doing-a-reasonable-job-as-diamond-mod/369#comment1039_368) for the continued presence of your question, this seems to be a particularly strong argument against your position. And you're precisely correct in divining that I don't like assholes. In fact, one of the primary roles of a ♦ moderator is to keep the site relatively asshole-free. The solution to end the friction seems obvious.

Comment: @CodyGray: It is not rare, expecially on a site such as this. In physics, where the answers are objective, I have had to correct 100% wrong answers with 20+ upvotes, this is typical. I am starting to understand why math.overflow is separate from this site, professional math folks know better than to trust the nietzscian supermen that run this place. Don't worry, my decisions regarding right and wrong are entirely decoupled from political voting, and yours should be as well.

Comment: "nietzscian supermen that run this place"? ugh. This discussion is getting further and further away from anything related to your actual question, @Ron. From the look of it, Cody would support your question were you to allow a small edit, mostly for tone. Surely that's a useful thing; make the edit, get the question re-opened, move on.

Comment: @Shog9: What edit? To remove "this is the stupidest thing I have ever read in a book?" from the question? Why? It _is_ the stupidest thing I have ever read in a book, and I have read some pretty stupid books. To not say it makes it look like I don't see this, it makes me look like I have an open mind regarding this. So, no, I don't accept the edits, and if this place doesn't encourage, welcome, and nurture _total assholes and dickwads_ (like me), then, what am I doing here?

Comment: @Ron: that sounds like a question you need to answer for yourself.

Comment: @Ron: If you're mind isn't open, then why are you asking the question in the first place?  Stack Exchange is not a discussion board, debate society, or place for people to evangelize their belief systems; you still seem to be missing this point.

Comment: @Ron: Just so you know, I probably won't chose to vote to reopen the question because I see no indication that its quality has been improved and it probably can't be answered any better than Michael Dorfman and commando already have.  In fact the most recent edit represents a moving target that seriously devalues the question _and_ its answers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I ask the question only as a rhetorical device--- it is something that many people ask, and it is objectively answerable by reading neitzsche. I have never met a philosopher who thinks nietzsche is not a racist, it is something he is proud of, and it is central to his thinking. I put it here for the purpose of _advertizing this_ and allowing people to know something quickly, so they don't have to read nietzsche's crackpot rants to discover this the hard way. The fact that people are arguing that nietzsche is _not racist_ just shows that a bunch of people here make stuff up.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Rhetorical questions are allowed, even encouraged. The upvoted anwers are a signal of what the community thinks at any one time, and this question is not only an embarassment to nietzsche, but to his apologists here.

Comment: @JonEricson: Michael Dorfman and commando gave incorrect answers that show no ability to read and understand what nietzsche is writing.  That these answers are upvoted just shows the voting system is busted, but this doesn't bother me, since it is to be expected given the state of discourse in philosophy. You should put questions and answers without editing, and without censorship, because it allows the true answers to emerge with time, as new eyes come in, and in this case, the racism is a central and important component of nietzsche which people have a vested interest in burying quietly.

Comment: Whether Nietszche is racist or not is not really relevant here... You seem to have difficulty staying on topic.

Comment: @RonMaimon Again... I'm the *last* person who'd have any interest in defending Nietzsche against anything. I *do* concede that there was an element of racism involved in his writings (e.g. in the passage about the Chinese you added after my answer). I do *not* concede that my interpretation is incorrect. Given that my philosophy teacher is a staunch Anti-Nietzscheian who despised every moment of his Nietzsche classes, yet agrees with my interpretation, clearly it is not only me who disagrees with Nietzsche's philosophy yet finds him defensible on *some* points.

Comment: @Ron: In that case, if this question were to be reopened, I'd immediately vote to close it as "Not a real question".  The really toxic thing about the post is that it discourages similar (but honest) questions.  I have a question about the relationship between Hitler and Nietzsche, but there's zero chance I will ask it in the near future.  (Maybe that's for the best in this _particular_ case, but not in general.)

Comment: Related: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/joke-questions-please-refrain/

Comment: @JonEricson: The relationship between hitler and nietzsche is very close to the relationship between lenin and Marx. The political implementation of an idea and the idea are different. This is a perfectly legitimate question, and there is no reason a person cannot ask it--- in fact "Was Hitler Nietzsche's Superman?" was a question here a few weeks ago, propmptly closed and deleted by the usual suspects, and the person who asked it is no longer active. This is one of the things that showed me nietzsche stuff is censored here.

Comment: @Shog9: These are not a joke, nor do they resemble jokes. They are suppressed things. It is like asking "Is cold fusion real?" on physics (when you know or strongly suspect that it is), or "Can you come out of a black hole?" when you suspect strongly that you can. These are encouraged types of questions, that appear on physics.stackexchange and are answered fairly and honestly from _all_ points of view. as asking and anwering them clarifies the literature. The nietzsche analogs are suppressed here for purely political reasons.

Comment: @commando: I understand your answer is sincere--- I accept that--- I just don't read that passage in the way you do. You don't go around deleting other answers or censoring questions which express an opinion different from yours, so I have no complaint. The fact that nietzsche despises weakness is well known, but he also clearly states that the anecdotal higher pain threshhold of certain Black people is _not_ a sign of strength of character, but of lack of normal pain response, which is an absurd and common 19th century racist idea.

Comment: @Ron, either you're asking a question you honestly want to see answered, or you're missing the purpose of the site. If you can't abide edits that preserve the former while softening the argumentative tone of the question, I tend to suspect the latter. See also: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/faq#editing

Comment: @Shog9: I accept edits that preserve the question, so long as they don't make me look tolerant of racism, or wanting to debate whether black people feel physical pain like the white folks do. This was my objection to the edits. There is no reason to remove opinionated statements from a question, you can just say they are incorrect (if they are incorrect). It is likely that others have the same opinionated point of view, so arguing that it is false is useful for others. Plus, well stated supportable opinions, in either direction. attract people to a site, and I think mine was well stated.

Comment: No one here is condoning racism, and my rephrasing did not imply that you were tacitly accepting it, either. This is yet another straw man argument; I expect more from someone who prides themselves so ostentatiously on speaking unbridled truth.

Comment: @CodyGray: You removed "This is the stupidest thing I have ever read." And replaced it with "The idea that pain hurts Black people less strikes me as a pretty ignorant observation". While superficially the same, the second is too mild, and makes it look like I want to debate if the quote is ignorant or not, which made me cringe. If you had said "This statement reads beyond the pale of reason, it is ridiculous." I would be ok. It's just a tone-deaf edit. I am aware you are not condoning racism, you just choose to phrase things in a way that is like nails down a chalkboard to my ears.

Comment: Ironically, your contributions read like "nails down a chalkboard" to the ears of 99% of the members of this community. I'm not sure why your ego is so inflated that you can't appreciate this fact. Why should we all arrange to satisfy you, rather than you arranging to satisfy others? This is not so much a philosophical question but a rhetorical one. No, it does not appear to anyone that you are seeking to debate the ignorance of this observation. For one thing, debating observations is not within the scope of this site. For another, the question actually being asked is sufficiently clear.

Comment: @CodyGray:The reason is because I am right, and all of you are wrong, as I am sure you all recognize already. It is incumbent on people to reject the majority in all cases, since majority vote and popularity contests are always a form of oppression. I am sure you already all know this, and I am sure all of your disagreements with me are insincere. It is embarassing to debate obvious points with people who are doing politics, it only serves as a warning to others--- devils be here, stay away. My writing sounds very good, because it is very good. I'm a pretty objective evaluator of my own stuff.

Comment: *"it only serves as a warning to others--- devils be here, stay away"* is precisely why I'm reconsidering my decision to leave this question visible.

Answer (score 14):

Y'know, there's nothing wrong with strong opinions.  But I've seen your posts, and I think you're going about this the wrong way.

Your user account profiles are a perfect place to put your personal philosophies, and I see that you have done that in spades.  Good for you.  To do the same thing in question and answers?  Totally inappropriate and unacceptable.

If you doubt this, consider this hypothetical scenario (for illustrative purposes only; I apologize in advance if I offend anyone).

You are at home having dinner, and you hear a knock at your front door.  You open the door, and a man in a suit is standing there holding a Bible.  He asks you if Jesus Christ is your personal savior, and then asks if he can come into your home to discuss it with you.  Before you decide, you find out that he's a Jehovah's Witness, and he tells you that the steak dinner you are eating is an abomination, because there's a passage in the Bible that says you shouldn't eat the blood of animals.

What would you do?

Now.  First of all, let me make something perfectly clear:  ***It doesn't matter what you or your visitor's beliefs are.***  My guess is your answer would be "No Thanks," and you would close the door without letting him in.

Well, that is *our* answer to your rants about Nietzsche.  ***No, thank you.***

Philosophy.SE ***is not your personal soapbox;*** it is a Question and Answer site.  If you wish to follow the prescribed *format* of the site, your future contributions are welcome.  Otherwise, there are plenty of other forums and discussion boards where you can more freely express yourself.

Comment: I am well aware of how this site works, and I express views when _they are relevant and important answering the question_. To expand your analogy, if I asked a Jehova's witness what is God's view of a steak dinner, I would expect this response. This is what is going on here, where a fellow comes in and says "Why is nietzsche calling Jews a priestly people?" The answer is because he hates priestly people, and considers them morally and aesthetically inferior. To prevent one from saying this is to protect nietzsche from criticism.

Comment: Perhaps I make my point better by pointing out that the JW is *insisting* that he come into your house to discuss it.  No, in fact, he's demanding it; he feels that it is *his right* to come into your house and save your sorry non-Christian ass.  Which is *exactly* what you are doing here.  The JW doesn't care *at all* about your steak dinner logic; he only cares about his agenda.

Comment: Seriously, no link to what SO is not (we should rename the post, or have a network-wide one at least)?

Comment: @casperOne: If this is what the higher level of SO looks like, why should I participate? You have no experts for a reason--- experts don't do your kind of politics.

Comment: @RonMaimon And civil people don't make ad-hominem attacks.  You sir, are out of line.

Comment: @RonMaimon "You have no experts" - disproof by counterexample: Jon Skeet

Comment: Please keep interaction, even in the comments, civil. I would encourage any extended discussion to be taken to chat.