# 2016 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Philosophy's [first moderator election](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: Joseph Weissman] [image: commando] [image: Camil Staps]

They'll be replacing [the pro tempore crew](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) shortly — please thank *everyone* for volunteering, congratulate the veterans on the job they did shepherding this site through the beta, and share your assistance and advice with the new folks as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6285076606222336/0).

Comment: Special thanks to Joseph Weissman for [doing a reasonable job](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/368/is-joseph-weissman-doing-a-reasonable-job-as-diamond-mod). Here's to another reasonable term of reasonable moderation!

Comment: Hip-hip hur-reasonable?

Comment: Also big thanks to @virmaior for doing a great job.

Comment: Many thanks to all who contribute to this community.  Congratulations and best wishes to the moderators.

Comment: I have been a member for only twelve days, but during that brief time I have received constructive feedback and guidance on multiple occasions from virmaior, Keelan, and commando. The moderators, and others, excel in assisting new users and in safeguarding the quality and integrity of Philosophy SE. I love it. :-)

Comment: glad to see the back of v., and commando never bugged me